# How I can use Bluesnap callback URL

Tags: bluesnap

I need a help. 
I tried to impliment one time payments with Bluesnap.
After payment I need to return user to site with needed parametr.

I found in documentation tow ways how can impliment it. 
I could use thankyou.backtosellerurl with encription or custom param.

I tried thankyou.backtosellerurl param but after payment nothing happens. I got default Bluesnap thank you page.

Than I tried to use custom1 param but also not got needed result. For Custom param I add settings on page design in admin panel http://joxi.ru/p27LM9EsKnXJQA

My code.

```
function generatePaymentLink($amount, $text = 'Pay Now'){
    return '<a class="payment-link" target="_blank" href="'.generatePaymentUrl($amount).'">'.$text.'</a>';
}

function generatePaymentUrl($amount){
    $config = getConfiguration();
    $res = request('https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/services/2/tools/param-encryption');
    if($config['sandbox_mode']){
        return $config['sandbox']['url'].'?merchantid='.$config['sandbox']['merchantid'].'&enc='.$res;
    }
    return $config['production']['url'].'?merchantid='.$config['production']['merchantid'].'&amount='.$amount;
}

function getConfiguration(){
    require_once (__DIR__.'/config.php');
    return $config;
}

function wrapCdata($string)
{
    return '<![CDATA['
    .str_replace(']]>', ']]><![CDATA[', $string)
    .']]>';
}

function paramEncryption(array $params)
{
    // compose request XML
    $params_xml = '';
    foreach ($params as $key => $value)
    {
        $key = wrapCdata($key);
        $value = wrapCdata($value);
        $params_xml .= "<parameter>\n<param-key>$key</param-key>\n
                <param-value>$value</param-value>\n</parameter>\n";
    }
    $request_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<param-encryption xmlns=\"http://ws.plimus.com\">\n
            <parameters>\n".$params_xml."  </parameters>\n</param-encryption>\n";
  return $request_xml;
}

function request($url, $http_method = 'POST')
{
    $request_xml = paramEncryption([
        'thankyou.backtosellerurl' => urlencode('https://siteurl.com/ipn-button.php?test=loremIpsum'),
        'amount' => 22,
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'custom1' => 'loremIpsumCustom'
    ]);
    $username = '//User';
    $password = '//Password';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'AIOP STORE',
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/xml'),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_xml);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $response_xml = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($response_xml === false)
    {
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response_xml);
    $json  = json_encode($xml);
    $configData = json_decode($json, true);

    return $configData['encrypted-token'];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To use the `thankyou.backtosellerurl` BlueSnap need to allow a specific permission on your account.

You should contact [BlueSnap support](https://support.bluesnap.com/) and ask them to do so

Answer (score 0):

using thankyou.backtosellerurl parameter requires BlueSnap to enable a permission on your account, but this parameter should be used only if you intend to pass different callback URLs on different transactions/ products / shopper location or any other logic on your end that requires you to set the callback URL as a parameter only when you create the checkout page., If this is the case you need to contact BlueSnap support and ask them to enable the relevant permission on your account.

If you have one fixed callback URL you can set it on your BlueSnap account console via Page Design -> settings.